# How/why did fstrim trim more space than I have free?

Tags: linux, ext4, fstrim

How/why did fstrim trim more space than I have free?

```
$ df -h /
Filesystem                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/drystone_2019-debian   93G   84G  4.6G  95% /

$ sudo fstrim -v /
/: 8.8 GiB (9395548160 bytes) trimmed

$ uname -r
4.19.0-6-amd64

$ head -n1 /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q: [df -h - "Used" space + "Avail" Free space is less than the total "Size" of /home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249387/df-h-used-space-avail-free-space-is-less-than-the-total-size-of-home)
>
> A: By default, ext2/3/4 filesystems reserve 5% of the space to be useable only by root.

(and the reserved space is not shown in "Available").